# float not expanding dynamically

Tags: html, css

i have css code column a and column b im using float in my code to expand column a dynamically but this isn't happening, i would like to do as much i add content in column b, column a to expand please see my code at http://jsfiddle.net/hadinetcat/E8jd3/

My code:

**CSS**

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;  
}

.right {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class = "container">
<div class="left">
column a
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
column a<br />
</div>


<div class="right">
column b<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />
dynamic row<br />

</div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have updated the code in JSFiddle,

```
check it here : http://jsfiddle.net/btCQn/1/

<style>
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
    position:relative;

}

.left {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;
  position:absolute;
}

.right {
  width: 45%;
  float: right;

}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".left").css("height",$(".right").height());
});
</script>
```

Its working

Comment: thank you for your effort and your code, but the problem the code isn't working in my browser im using IE6. column a isn't expanding as i add row in column b, but the code is working in JSFiddle. please check and let mr know thanks.

Comment: @Hadi : I'm checking.

Comment: @Hadi: I have updated the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/btCQn/1/ , with jquery function and tested for IE6, its working

Comment: one more thing if i remove height:100%; from .container it show all content in column b. in IE10 working fine. but not other IE 8,7,6,

Comment: did u add the JQuery function? $(document).ready(function(){
$(".left").css("height",$(".right").height());
});

Comment: @ Viji, sorry for the late reply. no isn't working, it show have blue color. the problem not only IE6 also IE 7,8,9,

Comment: Did u add the jquery.js?

Comment: @ Viji, you mean <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".left").css("height",$(".right").height());
});
</script> ?? i have added too but not working.

Comment: And also u have to include jquery1.8.js. Then only jquery functions will work.

Comment: how to add jquery1.8.js. ?? im new to this

Comment: im using php and css in Linux not windows so adding jquery1.8.js. well be difficult, can we do it in css only

Comment: It doesn't matter. Jquery is light weight and can use in any lang, any platform n its pretty fast too

Comment: You can download from jquery.com/download and save it in your local n link it or you can give directgGoogle CDN link <script SRC="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @hadi : hi, for you reference i have updated the code in the answer

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `display:table` for your parent and then `display:table-cell` for the columns

### CSS

```
<style>
.parent {
    display: table;  
    width:100%;
}

.left {
    display: table-cell; 
    width:200px;
    background-color:#0c0;
}

.right {
    width:auto;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color:#f00;
}

.footer {
    background-color:#eee;
}
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<body>

    <div class="parent">
         <div class="left">aaaa</div>
         <div class="right">bb<br />bbb<br />bbb</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">Footer</div>

</body>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2JmBL/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution (JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Yjeq2/1/)

(no changes to your HTML)

CSS

```
<style type="text/css"> html, body {
    font-family:verdana;
    font-size:12px;
}
.parent {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.left {
    border:1px solid blue;
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:3px 0;
}
.right {
    border:1px solid green;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    padding:3px 0;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

 .left, .right {
    padding-bottom:8000px;
    margin-bottom:-8000px;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 lightblue;
}
.clr {
    clear:both;
}
.footer {
    border:1px solid orange;
    position: relative;
    padding:3px;
    margin-top:5px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use CSS expressions. They're not well supported.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux - calc is ok except for ie8 and android- see http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @fred02138, the code working in IE 10 only but not in IE 9,8,7,6. can you please check it again. thanks for your effort.